# React Native - How to start another animation conditionally

Tags: react-native, animation

I want to create my own loader using animation, my idea is using scale to handle it, so the step should be like:

1. show an image scale from (n) to 1 for the first time
2. check if conditional is accepted or not
3. if conditional accepted, show an image scale from 1 to (n)

I can achieve 1st condition, but when i try 2nd and 3rd condition, the animation start in a blink of eye,

anyone can help me how to fix this?

here's the code i've tried:

```
//animation function
playAnimation(){
  this.setState({onLoad:true})
  this._load.setValue(0)
  this._scale.setValue(0)
  Animated.timing(this._load, {
    toValue: 100,
    useNativeDriver: true,
    duration:1000
  }).start(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      Animated.timing(this._scale, {
        toValue: 100,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        duration:1000
      }).start(()=>this.setState({onLoad:false}));
    }, 2000);
  });

  onLoad = this._load.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50, 75, 100],
    outputRange: [10, 1, 1.4, 1],
  })

  imageScale = this._scale.interpolate({
    inputRange: [20, 35, 70],
    outputRange: [1.2, 1, 20],
  })
}

//on render
<Animated.Image
  style={{
    resizeMode:'contain',
    position:'absolute',
    zIndex:1,
    width:width/2,
    height:200,
    transform:[{scale:this.state.onLoad?onLoad:imageScale}]
  }}
  source={{uri: "https://www.knittedhome.com/communities/5/004/012/872/235/images/4628207884.jpg"}}
/>
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: what's the reason for your setTimeOut

Answer (score 0):

How your code works right now is somewhere in your code, you're calling `PlayAnimation()`.

`PlayAnimation()` will:

1. start and complete first animation
2. Wait 2 sec
3. start and complete second animation

What you're doing in your `Animated.Image` is setting the transforms to different values.  This doesn't start or stop the animation, just tells `Animated.Image` what value to set transform to.

**What you should do**

Use one `Animated.Value` to keep track of the scale.  Assign that value to the `Animated.Image` transform.

Write two Animation functions:

1. `scaleDown`, call this where you're currently calling PlayAnimation
2. `scaleUp`, use your onLoad conditional to execute this in render or somewhere appropriate.